# Hibernate execute update with criteria

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, orm

Is it possible to execute an update while using `Criteria` in `Hibernate`? For example:

```
Session session = getSession();
Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(User.class);
crit.add(Restrictions.eq("token", sessionToken));

User user= new User();
Transaction tx = session.getTransaction();
try 
{
    tx.begin();
    session.updateWithCriteria(user, crit); //my imaginary function 
    tx.commit();
}
catch (Exception e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace();
    tx.rollback();
}

session.close();
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a very powerful feature called:

#### [15.4. DML-style operations](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch15.html#batch-direct)

*small cite from doc:*

> ... However, Hibernate provides methods for bulk SQL-style DML statement execution that is performed through the Hibernate Query Language...

So, while this is not about **`criteria`** - we still can use our domain model for querying, because it is about **HQL**. This is a snippet showing the power:

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

String hqlUpdate = "update Customer c set c.name = :newName where c.name = :oldName";
// or String hqlUpdate = "update Customer set name = :newName where name = :oldName";
int updatedEntities = s.createQuery( hqlUpdate )
        .setString( "newName", newName )
        .setString( "oldName", oldName )
        .executeUpdate();
tx.commit();
session.close();
```

SUMMARY: Having that in place:

- we can use query to filter results
- we can apply bulk update on it
- we won't need to load these rows in memory, into the session...

Comment: Summary: it is **not possible** to run a DML using Criteria

Comment: What is the variable s?

Answer (score 13):

Now we can do something like this for bulk update and delete. New api's released for criteriaUpdate and CriteriaDelete

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = this.em.getCriteriaBuilder();
// create update
CriteriaUpdate<Order> update = cb.createCriteriaUpdate(Order.class);
// set the root class
Root e = update.from(Order.class);
// set update and where clause
update.set("amount", newAmount);
update.where(cb.greaterThanOrEqualTo(e.get("amount"), oldAmount));
// perform update
this.em.createQuery(update).executeUpdate();
```

Comment: can you explain more clearly how this query translates to normal SQL query for reference

Comment: Is it needed to start the transaction before call ```executeUpdate()``` ? Or it's not?

Answer (score 1):

First you should get the object then modify and update:

```
   Query q = session.createQuery("from StockTransaction where tranId = :tranId ");
   q.setParameter("tranId", 11);
   StockTransaction stockTran = (StockTransaction)q.list().get(0);

   stockTran.setVolume(4000000L);
   session.update(stockTran);
```

If you want to use partial/dynamic update feature then put

```
@org.hibernate.annotations.Entity(
        dynamicUpdate = true
)
```

annotation on top of the dao class.

Example from: http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-dynamic-update-attribute-example/

Note: The Question is "with criteria" but the accepted answer is NOT "with criteria" but SQL.